# Javascript dot operator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dot-operator

I am a javascript noob so i dont understand why in the code below the author uses Avengers.cast instead of just Avengers?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.factory('Avengers', function() {
        var Avengers = {};
        Avengers.cast = [{
            name: "Robert Downey Jr.",
            character: "Tony Stark / Iron Man"
        }];
        return Avengers;
    })


function AvengersCtrl($scope, Avengers) {
    $scope.avengers = Avengers;
}
```

Comment: He is setting a property `cast` on the object `Avengers`. It can be accessed using the same notation.

Comment: @lethal-guitar: Well there's also the question of why set it on the property instead of the variable...

Comment: apparently design decision - the Avengers object will probably have more properties in the future than just the cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var Avengers = {};
```

This means: create a new object and refer to it by the variable Avengers

```
    Avengers.cast = [{
        name: "Robert Downey Jr.",
        character: "Tony Stark / Iron Man"
    }];
```

This means: the object just created now has a property called `cast`. This is an Array and contains exactly one object (with two properties with String values).

Comment: So why declare var Avengers = {}; and Avengers.cast when the code seems to work just the same when i delete the var Avengers = {}; line and change Avengers.cast to Avengers? Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `cast` property of `Avengers` is set to specific object. Let say, initially `Avengers` has no value. In factory section, `Avengers` became

```
Avengers.cast = [{
    name: "Robert Downey Jr.",
    character: "Tony Stark / Iron Man"
}];
```

You can use this somewhere in your code like `console.log(Avengers.cast)`. Following example for the function;

```
myApp.factory('Avengers', function() {
    return {
        helloWorld: function() {
            return "Hello, World!"
        }
    };
});
```

You can use `Avengers.helloWorld()` somewhere in your code.

As summary, you can create objects with angular.js factory and set property for that object also create functions in that object. Refer [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services)  for more details

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question: there is more than one way to pass information around.

The author could have made the `Avengers` service just the array instead of an object with the array.

So the choice was somewhat arbitrary, as you seem to be picking up on.

That said if the author is planning on extending the `Avengers` service with more properties, then that is why an object with the array was chosen.

Although if you're just going to do that you should check out [`constant`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/object/%24provide#constant) - maybe it would be more appropriate than `factory`.